# How do you turn an audio wave represented by values into a wavetable using Fast Fourier Transform?

Tags: javascript, fft, web-audio-api

I've scoured a lot of articles and links and questions here but I really can't get my head around FFT's. I'm simply trying to convert an array of values that represents a waveform, [0, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0, -0.5, -1, -0.5] for example, into a wavetable for use with Javascript's WebAudio. I've found a library (fft.js) and scoured source code of people's implementations of it but for the life of me I can't work it out! I know I need a complex array of real and imag values but I just don't know the order of the steps to get there.

Any help much appreciated.